# Angularjs routing in different files

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I'm checking out angular routing.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm

The examples I see have all the routes be defined in the same file. How do I have various routes be defined in different files / modules?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In AngularJS routes are defined in configuration block. Each AngularJS module can have multiple configuration blocks and you can define routes in each and every configuration block. The final routing for the entire application is a sum of routes defined in all modules.

In practice you can do it like:

```
angular.module('myModule1', []).config(function($routeProvider){
  //define module-specific routes here
});

angular.module('myModule2', []).config(function($routeProvider){
  //define module-specific routes here
});

angular.module('myApp', ['myModule1', 'myModule2']).config(function($routeProvider){
  //define app-level routes here
});
```

Regarding the split over files - I guess this largely depends on how you split AngularJS modules in files. What I would recommend is sticking to one-file equals one-module principle.

You can see all this applied to a larger-scale web application in angular-app, an effort to build a reference for a non-trivial application written in AngularJS:

- https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

In the mentioned app you can see routes defined in multiple files, ex.:

- https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projectsinfo/projectsinfo.js
- https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projects/projects.js

Comment: What about in the case that a module sets up a route with a resolve property that depends on a provider and that module is specified as a dependency of the main app module? Considering the provider setting would be set in the app module, would the resolve property still work?

Answer (score -1):

You can make the Angular application with different files without specifing them
follow this steps

**Step 1**: Get the full url

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
```

**Step 2** Sorting the filename alone

`var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

**Step 3** Displaying the result

```
alert(filename);
```

I have done this in w3schools try it editor
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDP3QTCP7V4E

Comment: This answer absolutely doesn't respond the original question